# childbrowser is not opening a page

Tags: xcode4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap 1.1.0 in xcode4.
When I added a link using anchor tag in body of html file with "http://google.com", it opened, but when I was trying to open a page from javascript in the childbrowser it just shows a blank page (about:blank).

This line did not work for me
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com");

I have added all external links, and there is no warning in the project.

Thanks,
regeint

Comment: Finally it worked.
I degrade my phonegap from v1.1.0 to v1.0.0 and it worked.
I think the childbrowser is not compatible for latest version of phonegap.